# Facebook Open Graph: Force to hide title and description on sharing link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

We're working on a Facebook app where you can dress yourself up via the webcam.
In an earlier stage of production, i had the perfect open graph tags for the image that we are sharing with the url. See below:

[Example of what i'm trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGWh3.jpg)

Now that all open graph tags are correct, for some reason the look of the shared link changed to this:

[The current look of the shared link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYi2S.png)

This causes our branding in the image to dissappear. Is it possible to force Facebook to hide the title from the shared url?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Cheers Daniel

These are the current open graph tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://pietmagazine.nl/nieuwepiet/_posters/pb385801451.jpg" />
<link rel="image_src" href="https://pietmagazine.nl/nieuwepiet/_posters/pb385801451.jpg"/>


<meta property="og:title" content="Piet Magazine: Nieuwe Piet" />
<meta property="og:url"    content="https://pietmagazine.nl/nieuwepiet/?id=pb385801451" /> 
<link rel="canonical" href="https://pietmagazine.nl/nieuwepiet/?id=pb385801451" />

<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXX"/>
```

Comment: No, you can not force that – Facebook decides how posts are displayed, and that can change even for the same post, depending on the viewing user, what device they are using, etc. Apart from providing images in the recommended dimensions (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images), there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thanks for your clear answer. So there's no good reason why de display method has suddenly changed?